# Just play and pause youtube video embedded in webpage?

Tags: embed

I need to add a Youtube video to a webpage, however, just working the "play" and "pause"... Without giving the visiting the option to see the progress bar or even click on the channel photo... Just play and pause...

The most you can do is this code without success:

```
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-50400e2 elementor-widget elementor-widget-html" data-id="50400e2" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="html.default"> 
<div class="elementor-widget-container"> 
<div style="position: relative; height: 0; padding-bottom: 56.2%; padding-top: 0;"> 
<iframe style="position: absolute !important; width: 100% !important; height: 100% !important; z-index: 100" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/EErSKhC0CZs?enablejsapi=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;hd=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;enablejsapi=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe> 
<div style="position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 70px;background-color: transparent;z-index: 101;left: 0;"></div> 
<div style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;width: 100%;height: 50px;background-color: transparent;z-index: 101;left: 0;"></div>
```

Exactly how this page is doing: https://www.tedswoodworking.com/new/vsl/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I have removed the incorrect tag "embedded" from your post.  Please take care when you add tags in future.  When you type a tag it shows you what it is for.

Comment: @Tom V 

Okay. Thanks, I'll look into that in the future. I live in Brazil and here it's a little difficult to find answers to my questions... That's why I decided to ask here... thank you :)

Comment: No problem I hope you get an answer!  I know about embedded but I can't tell you anything about embed.